# Android resources not loading

Tags: android, resources

i'm dealing with resources issue for a while and i cannot figure it out. The thing is that my resources(shapes, gradients, layouts) don't load up in application like they should.  For instance:

My "layout.xml" file (main layout for activity)

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/favourite_rest"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/activ_favourite_bck"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
            ...
```

And layout for background: "activ_favourite_bck.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#55555555"
    android:centerColor="#77777777"
    android:centerY="0.5"
    android:endColor="#55555555"
    android:angle="270" />
  </shape>
```

In this case when i run my application, brackground is pure black like no background is set, but when i rename the file with background definition from activ_favourite_bck.xml to "halabala.xml" ( with changing reference in main layout android:background="@drawable/halabala") the background is there and everything is working fine. I want to name my resources with purpuse so later when i have more of them there is no mess. I know there is naming convention that resource filename can contain only small characters with "_" and that's what i'm fallowing.

Note: the file is recognized by IDE, there are no errors during building and i can reference file from code.

I'm woring with android 1.6 api, but i tried changing to 2.0, 2.2.. with no success. I also tried various phone types and emulator and i tried changing IDE from eclipse to IDEA and nothing helps. I tried rebuilding project, refreshing everything that can be refreshed:) i tried to wipe the application from devices with no effect.  Is anybody facing similar issue like me?

Btw. the same thing is going on when i put some picture(png) in drawable folder and i'm referencing it from xml. Some pictures are recognized (and shown in running application) and some not( they are recognized only after renaming to sometning else).

Comment: Does anything show up in logCat?

Comment: logCat doesn't mention issue with resources or something relevant, but i noticed that if i move background definition from drawable folder into layout folder, problem dissapears and everything works fine. It is kind of a solution but i don't really like it. I don't know how it will work for images (not mentioning handling images with different resolution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of hours i worked this out. I probaly accidentally removed folder **drawable-mdpi**. After creating it and copying images there everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an arbitrary image called a.png or some such (so it sorts alpha above your real drawable)  ...